# Will light of 405nm wavelength behave in a single mode (SM) fiber , in multimode manner?

Tags: speed-of-light, wavelength, fiber-optics

Since the wavelength of 405nm is substantially shorter than the wavelengths of 1310-1550nm, and since the ratio of the diameter of a single mode fiber core to the wavelength, at 405nm, is several times larger than at 1550nm, will then the 405nm light travel in the SM fiber in a multimode manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that shorter wavelenghts will travel through the fiber as a higher order mode.

[image: V-number]

Here you can see the V-number Vs. b parameter.

V-number is proportional to the wavelength as $V= 2\pi a (NA)/\lambda \sqrt{2\Delta}$ where $\Delta$ is the refractive index contrast between the core and the cladding. The b-number is proportional to the propagation constant and $b \approx (\beta/k - n_2)/(n_1 - n_2)$. You can find some further information here. https://www.fiberoptics4sale.com/blogs/archive-posts/95048070-basic-optics-for-optical-fiber

For C-band (1530-1565nm), you would see that the cutoff frequency (or cutoff wavelength) is close to the C-band wavelengths. Therefore, all other shorter wavelength modes "fit" inside of the fiber, so you would measure higher order modes.